# Given a square matrix, can it be written as the product of any invertible matrix and every square matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

If $A,B$ are $n\times n$ matrices with entries in a field $F$, and $M$ is an invertible $n\times n$ matrix, can $A$ be written as a product $A=MB$ for every $B$? I.e., given an $A$, can you choose an $M$ for every $B$ such that $A=MB$? Can you transform every $B$ into $A$?

Edit: Okay, there are some clear counters for when $A$ is the zero matrix (or when it isn't, it still doesn't work when $B$ is the zero matrix). So maybe it's a bit more interesting if we consider that both must be nonzero? What happens then?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  What if $A$ is the zero matrix and $B$ is the identity?

Comment: What if $B$ is a zero matrix and $A$ is not?

Comment: @J. W. Tanner I see, if $A$ is the zero matrix, it doesn't work for every $B$, and if $A$ isn't, you can't find an $M$ for nonzero $B$ that satisfies this condition. However, what about beyond this case? What if we only consider nonzero $A$ and $B$?

Comment: We have det($MB)=$det$(M)$det$(B)$, so if det$(B)=0$ and det($A)\ne0$, $A=MB$ won’t work, even if $B$ is nonzero (and obviously $A$ is nonzero if det($A)\ne0$)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given two matrices $A, B$, not necessarily square, of the same size, there exists an invertible matrix $M$ such that $A = MB$ *if and only if* $A$ and $B$ have the same kernel (nullspace). This is a nice exercise and produces many counterexamples to slight variations on your question. Note that in particular this condition implies that $A$ and $B$ have the same rank, by the rank-nullity theorem.

Similarly, there exist two invertible matrices $M, N$ such that $A = MBN$ iff $A$ and $B$ have the same rank, and there exists an invertible matrix $N$ such that $A = BN$ iff $A$ and $B$ have the same image.

Comment: Is this the same as saying $A$ and $B$ must row reduce to the same echelon form?

Comment: @minivase: yes, that's right.

Answer (score 2):

Consider, for a counterexample, the matrix $B=\begin{pmatrix}0 &1\\0 &0 \end{pmatrix}$ with real entries.

It is non-zero, but its determinant is $0$, so for example you will never find an invertible matrix $M$

such that $I=\begin{pmatrix}1 &0\\0 &1 \end{pmatrix}=MB,$ because that would mean $\det(I)=1=\det(M)\det(B)=0$.

Comment: In accordance with the answer of [Qiaochu Yuan](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/232/qiaochu-yuan), it is apparent that $I$ and $B$ have different kernels